# 8 channel recording with 32bit width audio not playing in audacity

Tags: audio, audio-recording, audacity, libalsa

I am able to record 8 channel mic audio (32bit audio but actual content is 24bit with 8 bit padding) in below format using alsa utils (pcm_read):

```
t0: channel 0, channel 1, channel 2, ....., channel 8
t1: channel 0, channel 1, channel 2, ....., channel 8
t2: channel 0, channel 1, channel 2, ....., channel 8
.
.
.
```

I am using below code to convert 32bit audio to 24bit audio but still audio played out is gibberish.

```
with open("input.raw", "rb") as f:
    x = open("output.raw", "wb")
    while f.read(1) != "":
        byte = f.read(3)
        x.write(byte)
    x.close()
```

Can anyone give me some pointers if I am doing anything wrong?

Comment: 1) Are you sure you're discarding the right byte? Perhaps it's the last byte of each sample, and not the first? (2) Is `input.raw` one channel of PCM data, or multiple channels interleaved? If it's interleaved, you'll have to account for that in which bytes you discard.

Comment: @Linuxios: let me check again.